# Transfering database part with EF or another tech

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, t-sql

I need to transfer a part of my database to a target database.
The structure of the database being complex, I wanted to know if it was possible to use EF in order to recover a complete graph of my source database in order to apply it in my target database, leaving to EF the care to manage the constraints of foreign keys.

Comment: EF is an Object Relational Mapper, it has nothing to do with data transfers. SQL Server already provides the tools you want - backup/restore, replication, schemas, Data Applications through DACPACs, database projects, schema comparisons. The question is very vague so it's impossible to suggest one option over the other. This is a very common and *old* problem, so all databases offer solutions.

Comment: `recover a complete graph of my source database in order to apply it in my target database,` any schema comparison tool can do this, like the one included in SSDT and Azure Data Studio. You can export the schema as a `Data-Application` from SSMS itself as a DACPAC file. You can compare a DACPAC with a real database the same way you can compare two databases, and apply the changes to the target

Comment: You can also create a [Database Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-database-project-extension?view=sql-server-ver15) using Azure Data Studio, put it in a Git repo for versioning, and deploy it as a DACPAC to another server or database

Comment: [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) on the other hand is used to constantly deploy data and schema changes to target databases to keep them in sync, either immediately or on a schedule

Comment: Hello, I have to create a tool which allows to migrate part of the data from a dev database to a prod database. The data comes from several tables and I have to make sure that the data fits into the target database without altering